# Assign each thread to its own logical core on a CPU with more than 64 cores

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, caching, cpu

For optimizing the performance of L1/L2 caches, I want to make sure that each thread runs on its own logical core only.
I've looked at [`SetProcessAffinityMask()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setprocessaffinitymask) , and for a CPU with less than 64 cores I can assign mask `1LL<<i` to thread `i`.

However, things get quite complicated with more than 64 CPU cores. Can someone explain simply what can I do to assign each thread to its own CPU core, while there can be multiple CPUs with more than 64 cores in total, or a single CPU with e.g. 96 logical cores?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/ProcThread/processor-groups

Comment: Does this result in better performance? I mean, the operating system already prefers to schedule threads on the same core. Likely, in my view, you are doing extra work that is likely to have no measurable benefit, and if anything, hurts performance slightly.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/numactl

Comment: @tinkertime Please don't link to linux.die, it is not kept up to date. And anyway, the question has the winapi tag.

Comment: Hi Serge Rogatch, have you checked the document as @Michael pointed out? If you get it working you can answer your own question.